# the type initializer for 'system.io.compression.zipfile' threw an exception error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, zip

I wanted to create a zip file with the code below in Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel. I am running this on a Windows XP Pro SP3.

*System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\TargetFolder", "C:\destination.zip")*

Initially there was an error as the class Compression.ZipFile was missing. After checking online, I've done 'Add Reference' for Compression, Compression.FileSystem & Compression.ZipFile. So, later, there is no error when compile/Build.

When I run the program and execute the command, the error below appears.

*The type initializer for 'System.IO.Compression.Zipfile' threw an exception. at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)*

I then tried the same code on Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework version 4.8.04084 SP1Rel and not such error occur.
Please help.

Comment: The `ZipFile` class wasn't introduced until .NET 4.5 so that is the minimum Framework version you can target and use that class. Try reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.5) in future and you'll learn these things for yourself.

Comment: As for references, the one and only reference you need for that class is *System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll*. Again, the documentation tells you that. Different assemblies may be required for different versions of .NET Core or .NET Standard but, for .NET Framework, there's just the one.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney.
There are some answers in a forum mentioned about this limitation and another said that adding the reference will enable it even in version 4. Anyway, well noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `ZipFile` class was not introduced until .NET Framework 4.5, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.8), any application targeting an earlier version will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It required framework 4.5 and above . If you want zip files in .net framework 4.0 then use shell. This might be useful to you
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257193/Easily-Zip-Unzip-Files-using-Windows-Shell

Comment: Thanks Yogesh.
I've tried this. I worked but the only limitation is, it will produce error if there is a file name with special character like Chinese character. I'll see how to move around it if there is no other option. Thanks.

Comment: @adrian  You are welcome. I did not check with special character . You have to sort out may be there is some way...